How to cite a reference in a footnote with no parentheses?
When I quote an author, my quotation goes into my footnote and it's fine. But, in a footnote, I’d like also to be able to cite a reference with no parentheses. How to do that?
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Winnicott1975,
address   = {Paris},
author    = {Winnicott, Donald Woods},
publisher = {Éditions Gallimard},
title     = {Jeu et réalité},
subtitle  = {L'espace potentiel},
year      = {1975},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{\autocite{Winnicott1975}}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


You can use \footcite{...}:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Winnicott1975,
address   = {Paris},
author    = {Winnicott, Donald Woods},
publisher = {Éditions Gallimard},
title     = {Jeu et réalité},
subtitle  = {L'espace potentiel},
year      = {1975},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text\footcite{Winnicott1975}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}

